# exported object wont recognize functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, es6-modules, es6-class

I have a module i have created using Js ES6.

the module has a function call that fails and says "dictionary.detectLangDictionary is not a function"
when it is defined and the object is recognized as such in the main js file but not in the function that calls - `dictionary.detectLangDictionary()`

I would like to understand why the object isnt recognized as an object and the function isn't recognized.

**The code and its structure:**

the module contains 4 file types:

1.the class defenition - dictionary.js:

```
export default class Dictionary
{
    sourceLanguage;
    destinationLanguage;
    dictionary;

    constructor(sourceLanguage,destinationLanguage,dictionary)
    {
        this.sourceLanguage=sourceLanguage;
        this.destinationLanguage=destinationLanguage;
        this.dictionary=dictionary;
    }


    detectLangDictionary(selectionText) {
    ...
    }

    static detectDictionaryFromList(textToDetect,dictionaryList)
    {
        let detectedDictionary=null;
        for (let dictionary in dictionaryList)
        {
            console.log("current dictionary is:",dictionary)
            detectedDictionary=dictionary.detectLangDictionary(textToDetect)
            if (detectedDictionary!=null)
            {
                return detectedDictionary;

            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

2.files which create dictionary objects and exports them - englishHebrewDictionary.js and englishRussionDictionary.js etc:

```
import Dictionary from "./dictionary.js";

let dict={
...
} 

export var EnglishHebrewDictionary=new Dictionary("English","Hebrew",dict);
```

3. a cumulative exports object that exports all the files of type 2 - dictionaries.js:

   export * from "./englishHebrewDictionary.js";
   export * from "./englishRussionDictionary.js";
   ...

4.the main program which calls everything:

```
import * as dictionaries from "./dictionaries/dictionaries.js"
import Dictionary from "./dictionaries/dictionary.js"
/**
 *detect which dictionary will fit and what the swaped text should contain
 */
function detectLangDictionary(selectionText) {
    console.log("dictionaries value:",dictionaries);
    return Dictionary.detectDictionaryFromList(selectionText,dictionaries);
}
```

the error: `dictionary.detectLangDictionary is not a function`

the results of the log:

main file detectLangDictionary function that recognizes the dictionaries as objects like it should:

```
  dictionaries value () : 
    {
    ​
    EnglishHebrewDictionary: Object { sourceLanguage: "English", destinationLanguage: "Hebrew", dictionary: {…} }
    ​
    EnglishRussionDictionary: Object { sourceLanguage: "English", destinationLanguage: "Russion", dictionary: {…} }
    ​}
```

the static Directory function that is called and doesnt recognize that EnglishHebrewDictionary is an object:

```
current dictionary is: EnglishHebrewDictionary
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do it looks like dictionaries is an object and not an array. The for loop is looping over the property names, I think you need to reference it like this.

```
dictionaryList[dictionary].detectLangDictionary(textToDetect)
```

So in your code it would look like this.

```
static detectDictionaryFromList(textToDetect,dictionaryList)
{
    let detectedDictionary=null;
    for (let dictionary in dictionaryList)
    {
        console.log("current dictionary is:",dictionary)
        detectedDictionary=dictionaryList[dictionary].detectLangDictionary(textToDetect);
        if (detectedDictionary!=null)
        {
            return detectedDictionary;

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```